# Traversing div on button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below HTML and am trying to get the text(Main Text and ChildText) on the Button(btnClick) for that particular Div(Number of Divs may differ at runtime)

```
<div class="main">
*** Some Main Text ***  <button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<div class="child">
<p> ** Some child Text ** </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
*** Some Main Text ***  <button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<div class="child">
<p> ** Some child Text ** </p>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried but am not sure how i ll do this with out unique ID Field  for  just with class name and thought there should be a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btnClick').click(function () {
    var mainText = '', childText;

    $(this).parent().contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function (i, el) {
        mainText += $(el).text();
    });

    childText = $(this).siblings('.child').text();

    alert(mainText);
    alert(childText);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkBRU/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('.btnClick').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).parent().text().split('\n')[1] + $(this).siblings('.child').text());
});
```

#### Demo

Comment: This gives both the text. But i want to have it seprately. one for main and other for child.

Comment: @user2067567 Updated answer and Fiddle too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.btnClick').click(function () {

    var mainText = $.trim($(this).closest('.main').text().split('\n')[0]);
    console.log('Main Text : ', mainText);

    var childText = $.trim($(this).next('.child').text());    
    console.log('Child Text : ', childText);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yJ6F2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).parent('div.main').text()` to get **all** of the text contained within `div.main` (this will include the text of all descendent elements).

If you want to get the text of `div.main` separately, you can do something like:

```
var mainText = $(this).parent('div.main').get(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

..and for the child text:

```
var childText = $(this).next('div.child').text();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE7Eh/3/)